# How can a primary key be inserted as foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key

Hi I am building an order intake form that will have information submitted belonging to 3 tables.  The order table will have the primary key used for the property and customer table.

How can I simultaneously create the primary key via the identity on the order table and insert that into the property and customer table?

SQL please.

Order
OrderKey PK

Property
OrderKey FK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insert multiple `Order` records (pick a new name that's not a keyword, by the way) then you need to use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).  Otherwise [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) should work.

Quick example using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`:

```
DECLARE @OrderID int

INSERT INTO
  Orders
   (<columns>
VALUES
 (....)

SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO
  Properties
   (OrderID, ...)
VALUES
  (@OrderID, ...)
```

Comment: i'll try this. Thanks it's actually orders (plural) for that reason

Comment: It worked.  Thanks for the quick response.  I used this in a SP and wasn't sure about what to put in the parameter for @OrderID so i left it blank.  It still populated to my table though.

Comment: In the SP you would declare `@ORDERID` as a variable internal to the SP, not as a param, and use it just like I listed above.

Comment: @Jayzihno It should be that way not because it conflicts with a keyword but because the table is a set of `orders`, not a set of `order`. IMHO. If you only ever had one order (or were only ever dealing with a single order at a time), there wouldn't be much point of having a table.